# Grails resources plugin not resolving Bootstrap CDN urls

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I've tried several things:

just using the url:

```
resource url: '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
```

local url with linkOverride:

```
resource url: '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', linkOverride: '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
```

using the baseurl mapper config:

```
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.modules = [
    core: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/"
]

resource url: 'bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', disposition: 'head'
```

None of these work. I always get some form of

> Resource not found:
>   //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Has the problem resolved? Was adding `http` helpful?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get back to this.  I will update when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Co-incidentally I am working on it right now as I see the question.
Looks like we have to explicitly use `http` for the CDN url.

```
resource url: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Same goes with `linkOverride`.

Comment: Why do their official documentation say to include it without `http:` ?